# PHPMailer Connects but not sending (Google XOAUTH2)

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Can anyone interpret the following output from PHPMailer and diagnose the problem? I have successfully tested my code in isolation but after incorporating into an application it fails

```
2021-08-19 14:25:31 3   Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2021-08-19 14:25:31 3   Connection: opened
2021-08-19 14:25:31 2   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q184sm1663611qkd.35 - gsmtp

2021-08-19 14:25:31 1   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

2021-08-19 14:25:31 2   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2607:fea8:e2c0:5dd:6c0a:3ddc:897:57d9]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

2021-08-19 14:25:31

2021-08-19 14:25:31 1   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2021-08-19 14:25:32 2   SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection q184sm1663611qkd.35 - gsmtp

2021-08-19 14:25:32 3   Connection: closed
```

The code is based on the XOAUTH2 example in the PHPMailer documentation. The essential function is here:

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
//Alias the League Google OAuth2 provider class
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;


class MainController extends Controller
{
    function sendPHPMail($to, $name, $reply, $subject, $body, $attach, $type) {
        // This function sends an HTML email via Google's SMTP server using XOAUTH2
                
        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();

        //Enable SMTP debugging
        //SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
        //SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
        //SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
        $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
            file_put_contents('smtp.txt', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "\t$level\t$str\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        };        
        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = $this->f3->get('mailHost');
        
        //Set the SMTP port number:
        // - 465 for SMTP with implicit TLS, a.k.a. RFC8314 SMTPS or
        // - 587 for SMTP+STARTTLS
        $mail->Port = 465;
        
        //Set the encryption mechanism to use:
        // - SMTPS (implicit TLS on port 465) or
        // - STARTTLS (explicit TLS on port 587)
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
        
        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        
        //Set AuthType to use XOAUTH2
        $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
        
        //Fill in authentication details here
        //Either the gmail account owner, or the user that gave consent
        $emailUser = $this->f3->get('mailUser');
        $clientId = $this->f3->get('oauthClientID');
        $clientSecret = $this->f3->get('oauthClientSecret');
        
        // Refresh Token obtained by configuring and running get_oauth_token.php
        // after setting up an app in Google Developer Console.
        $refreshToken = $this->f3->get('oauthRefreshToken');
        //Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
        $provider = new Google(
            [
                'clientId' => $clientId,
                'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            ]
        );
        
        //Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
        $mail->setOAuth(
            new OAuth(
                [
                    'provider' => $provider,
                    'clientId' => $clientId,
                    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
                    'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
                    'userName' => $emailUser,
                ]
            )
        );
        
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        //For gmail, this generally needs to be the same as the user you logged in as
        $mail->setFrom($emailUser, "Mississippi Valley Textile Museum");
        $mail->addReplyTo($reply);
        
        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress($to, $name);
        
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        
        //Set HTML message body, convert referenced images to embedded
        //Specify a basic plain-text alternative body
        $mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
        $mail->msgHTML($body);
        
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->AltBody = 'This email is HTML; enable HTML mail if you cannot see it.';
        
        //Add attachment if specified
        if ($attach) {
            $mail->addStringAttachment($attach, "MVTM{$type}.pdf");        }
        
        //send the message, catch and log errors
        try {
            return $mail->send();
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            file_put_contents('smtp.txt', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "\n$e->errorMessage\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
            return false;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            file_put_contents('smtp.txt', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "\n$e->errorMessage\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            // error messages from anything else
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It appears to get by the initial connection but not the actual transmission to the smtp server

Comment: You should never need to disable certificate verification when connecting to gmail; if you're getting errors it's because of a misconfiguration of your server, read the troubleshooting guide for more about that. I can't help much without seeing your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. OK, there is nothing wrong with my code as shown here. The problem was in my app config file which hold the ClientSecret and RefreshToken. I had used single rather than double quotes which caused an escape to be misinterpretted. 3 days wasted but lesson learned.